# Optimizing VBA copy/paste functions and loops

Tags: vba, loops, optimization, copy-paste

I have a large Excel sheet. I'm interested in moving data from one cell to another. I have researched on how to optimize the copy/paste function to take as little time as possible and found that:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Sheet1.Range("B1").Value
```

or

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("B1")
```

is faster than:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Copy
Sheet1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode=False'Clear Clipboard
```

Now, I need to make a copy with the following options:

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy

Range("B1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
```

Is it possible to translate that into the code similar to one of the previous mentioned?

Also, in regard to loops. Is it generally faster to avoid them (if possible) or how is the Compiler optimized? Let me give you an example so you don't misunderstand me:

Lets say I want to Copy values from "A1:A200" to "B1:B200". Which method would then be better in general?

```
Dim counter As Integer
For counter = 1 To 200
Sheet1.Range("A" & CStr(counter)) = Sheet1.Range("B" & CStr(counter))
End counter
```

Or is it better to simply use the code:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:A200").Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("B1:200")
```

These examples are of cause grossly simplified, though if someone could help me understand the principles applied, it would be of great value to me!

Comment: the fastest way to copy an entire range would be using `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A200").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B200").Value` , if you only want to copy the values

Comment: A with loop is simply a grouping of commands applied to a similar sheet for example. Therefore it is technically quicker than writing out each code line by line and executing them

Comment: Copying a range will me more faster then looping on the copy. But the true function that will reduce the copying time should be the deactivation of the screen update (Application.ScreenUpdating = False before the copy and Application.ScreenUpdating = True after the copy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't use `Select` and `Selection`. This really slows your code. Especially in loops.

The fastest way to copy values is to simply do this `Range("B1:B99").Value=Range("A1:A99").Value`

Furthermore you should deactivate Screenupdating and especially if formulas referr to the paste area switch off the automated calculation of the worksheet: `Application.ScreenUpdating=False
Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual`

In total it should somehow look like this:

```
Sub CopyFast ()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B99") = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A99")

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But this really gets important when copying huge amounts of values e.g. in loops instead of the simple copying task in this example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up doing it with the disabled interface and the direct copy commands. The sheet now takes 1 minute to execute instead of 5 minutes (on a fast computer). It includes loops, different function calls and a lot of sheets. This really helped a lot!